# how to verify a method of a non-mock object is called?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

It seems mockito only verifies whether a method of a mock object is called and the mock object always have something like `doReturn().when(mock object)`

But can I create a mock object and define `doReturn().when(mock object)`
and then verify a method of another object is called?

Here is what I want to do: I define a mockEnvironment and return a response no matter what happens. But then I want to verify different methods of anotherObj is called in different cases.

How to do that?

```
public class BaseClass {
    private Environment mockEnvironment;
    @Test
    public void testcase () {
     setMockitoEnvironment(); 
     response = foo(mockEnvironment, argument1);
     verify(anotherObj).codePath1(...);
     response = foo(mockEnvironment, argument2);
     verify(anotherObj).codePath2(...);
   }
}

//this method successfully return a response with any input 
//because I do not care how response is eventually generated, 
//I only care whether code path reaches createResponse() via 
//code path 1 or code path 2.
private void setMockitoEnvironment() {
    mockEnvironment = mock(Environment.class);
    doReturn (response).when(mockEnvironment).createResponse(for any input);
}
private Response foo(...) {
    ... 
    return createResponse(...);
}
```

Answer (score 188, accepted):

You can use a Mockito [Spy](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.29/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13) for this. If you setup `anotherObj` as a spy you can verify method calls on that object. In your example you need to make sure that the call to `foo` uses the spy instead of an ordinary implementation of `anotherObj`. The spy is setup something like this:

```
AnotherClass anotherObjSpy = Mockito.spy(new AnotherClass());
// do stuff -- e.g. anotherObjSpy.foo(...);
verify(anotherObjSpy).codePath1(...);
```

Comment: That means I may need to create and inject multiple mocked objects if I want to verify multiple things? that is not convenient.

Comment: @user389955 yes, you need to setup each object you want to check as a spy. As far as I know there is no way around that. Mockito needs to add a proxy to the objects and someone must tell Mockito which objects to proxy.

Comment: Instead of saying "//do stuff" it might be helpful to add that it is the "anotherObjSpy" that must make the method call being tested.

Comment: Thanks @jwehrle, you need to use the anotherObjSpy in the calls, otherwise the tests won't work.

Comment: I have a final method which I can't call spy on

Answer (score 13):

Annotate the non-mock object with `@Spy` annotation and then check for `verify()`. Check [this](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy)

Comment: Nice. works fine if we dont have to initialise the `@Spy` annotated object. But if we want to initialise it in `@Before` then dont use `@Spy` annotation but do it inside the `@Test` class as "val someName = Mockito.spy(objectYouWantToSpy)"

Comment: I have used `@SpyBean` for a `@SpringBootTest` integration test - [more details](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-spy-vs-spybean)